# How to change one half of a split pane while keeping the other the same when an action occurs in javafx

Tags: java, layout, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

I am trying to create an application in javaFX that has two main halves to it. One side where you have a set of buttons or controls, and the other where it displays a different set of data for each button pressed, almost as if one side changes scenes, but the point is, layout panes count as scenes and I am still trying to figure out how to dynamically change one side while the other remains static. If you know how to accomplish this(Ideally with a split pane), then that would be a great help, as I am yet to find this question answered.

Thanks

Comment: Just change the contents of the layout in the second part of the `splitpane` will get the job done. Have you tried something which doesn't work, if yes please add them to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SplitPane` has a [`.getItems()`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html#getItems--) method.

Use that and [`.set()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) the content you want at the correct index.

Comment: This has worked for me in a normal javaFx file, but i have not been able to make it work using FXML, is there anything else i should be doing?  This was just a simple test to see if it would work: `public void changeDisplay(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
  AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/test.fxml"));
  splitPane.getItems().set(1, pane);
 }`